# Change timezone of openshift DIY application

Tags: timezone, openshift, redhat

I have created the DIY application in the openshift. Now I want to change the default timezone of my application server.I tried some normal linux methods to do so but could not able to do so, due to root permission problem.Please tell me how can I do this.

Thanks,
Vinay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to change the timezone on the server as that would require administrative priviledges.  If you would like a specific timezone to be used in your code then you would need to account for that using whatever programming language you are using for your application.  You should be able to easily use UTC or whatever you would like.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem with timezone in my diy app (clojure), as i use jvm these worked for me

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=Europe/Moscow"
```

in .openshift/action_hooks/start